# Editd PDF Keywords but cannot search through them

Tags: pdf, search

I just finished scanning more than 10,000 documents and I save them as PDF but as they're scanned so I cannot search through their contents.

Then I decided to use [this](http://www.a-pdf.com/infochanger/) program and add some keyword to each PDF file.(Title,Subject and Keywords came as a default additional field in PDF format)

[image]

But unfortunately I cannot search through either title,subject or keyword in windows search; However those additional details appear when I other windows explorer like CubicExplorer but still I cannot search through them.

any idea/solution would be a great ... preferably not an online service, Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Install PDF iFilter and use standart Windows Search or WDS 4 at Windows XP/2000.

[Acrobat Help / Acrobat X | Reader X 32-bit and 64-bit iFilter](http://helpx.adobe.com/acrobat/kb/acrobat-x-ifilter.html)

[Adobe PDF iFilter 9 for 64-bit platforms](http://www.adobe.com/support/downloads/detail.jsp?ftpID=4025)

[ACROBAT AND ADOBE READER IFILTER ! PDF!](http://www.adobe.com/devnet-docs/acrobatetk/tools/AdminGuide/Acrobat_Reader_IFilter_configuration.pdf)

<kbd>Win</kbd>+<kbd>R</kbd>

```
search-ms:query=(ext:.pdf) "filesystem"
```

Run search query WDS 4:

[image: run search query WDS 4]

WDS 4 Result:

[image: WDS 4 Result]

Adobe Acrobat XI Search instance:

[image: Adobe Acrobat XI Search instance]

WDS 4 Status:

[image: WDS 4 Status]

## [IFilter Explorer](http://www.citeknet.com/Downloads/tabid/53/Default.aspx):

[image: IFilter Explorer old tools]

Comment: @Karan Even as indexes. I'll tell you more if you put iFilters such as Autodesk is able to search for text within the drawings.

Comment: +1 Interesting, seems it does work. Wonder why Sammy had problems with it then.

Comment: @Karan May be `IFilter Explorer` help?

Comment: Maybe. I did tell him about IFilter Explorer in another question. Anyway, it's not my problem, and not the OP's problem here so don't worry about it.